# Is there a way to override the Google Directions service zoom values?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, map-directions

I'm using the code below to get the route between two points:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
}
```

It's working fine, but I don't want to change my map position and zoom level when drawing route. So when I call the code above with different latitude and longitude values, I would like my map position and zoom level to be maintained.
Any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you create the `DirectionsRenderer`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer), you can pass a `DirectionsRendererOptions`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) object to the constructor function or you can call the `DirectionsRenderer.setOptions` method if you would like to change the options at some time after creation.

You can use the `preserveViewport` property of the `DirectionsRendererOptions` object to control how the renderer will interact with the map. Setting `preserveViewport` to `true`will leave the map display unchanged:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setOptions({ preserveViewport: true });
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes the error stop showing, but still the route doesn't draw well, looks like there is some data missing:

```
directionsDisplay.setOptions({ preserveViewport: true });
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
```