# Google map zoom not show like i save it

Tags: google-maps

i am using google maps in order to give some directions from one point to another.

Although, i have set the zoom of the map to 15 the zoom changes after the response of the direction request in order probably to fit the directions into the map.

Does anyone nows how to keep the zoom constant at 15. and focus at the first point?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do not change map center when rendering directions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085305/do-not-change-map-center-when-rendering-directions)

Answer (score 0):

In your `DirectionsRendererOptions`, set this option:

```
 preserveViewport: true
```

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions